# chmod recursive for group but exclude a single file

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

I'm trying to recursively allow a group to read a directory and skip a single file that is contained in within the directory (I am the designated owner of the directory but not for the single file to be skipped for the group).

To put another way, when I run `chmod -R g+r /path/to/directory`, no error is thrown and the command does not seem to work due to the single file that is owned by a different user and I want to ignore it (I also tried with `-f` and got the same result).

Is there a command to do this? Please advise.

Comment: You could first run the command you have and then run `chmod` again to undo the first `chmod` for that one file. Doesn't scale well, but if it's just one file...

Comment: What makes you say that the command does not appear to work?

Comment: Perhaps ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/